# Linux - How do I make a single folder RW and the rest of the filesystem RO?

Tags: linux, filesystems, read-only

I have successfully configured my Debian Linux's file system to be read-only. I made several changes, however the file relevant to this question is `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,ro,noatime,errors=remount-ro  0       1
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=30M,mode=1777    0    0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=30M,mode=1777    0    0
```

This is working great, but I want my `/home` directory to be "rw" (Of course, without losing any data), how do I do that? Everything is on a single hard drive in a single partition.

Comment: You don’t. Use separate partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to have a read-write folder on a read-only filesystem. If you want to make your filesystems read only, you should create a different filesystem for `/home` to have that mounted read-write.

1. Create a partition using `fdisk`
2. Run `mkfs.ext4 /path/to/partition`
3. Move /home to /home.old (`mv /home /home.old`)
4. `mkdir /home`
5. Edit `/etc/fstab` to include your newly created filesystem
6. `mount /home`
7. Copy all files to the new filesystem (`cp /home.old/* /home/`)
8. Remove all files from the old filesystem (`rm -rf /home.old`)

Comment: +1 To resize the partition without losing data you'd also have to use `resize2fs`. The most straightforward way is to do it with `gparted`, which is a nice GUI for all of those tasks. Boot from a live CD or a USB drive (e.g. Ubuntu is a simple choice and Unetbootin is an easy tool to create a USB disk with if you want), then run `gparted` on the drive; shrink and create as needed. Back up first, of course.

Comment: Also adding, it looks like the OP is doing this on an SD card. I actually used almost the same strategy after literally having 38 of 40 SD cards (38 of 38 Kingstons failed in a bad way, 2 of 2 SanDisks survived) in a site installation fail within a week of each other after about 3 months. Everything was made ro except an area for remote software updates; /var/cache and /var/log placed on ram disk. Some tips: run `fstrim` once on the read-only filesystem, mount your rw filesystem with `discard`, and if risk of rw data loss on power failure is acceptable, disable journaling on the rw system.

Comment: I am indeed using an SDcard and a Raspberry Pi system. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Can I achieve a similar result without messing with things on the filesystem level? I could make the FS Read-write and then use chmod on all folders to make them read-only, and exclude /home. The only problem is that root will not care about chmod.

Comment: Of course you could, but that's not what you asked ;) (a common problem on Q&A sites where people don't add a background story to their question, see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/257688)) And as you said, root is still able to access all files.